# Posgres Regex - any text between the initial and final text

Tags: c#, regex

I need to mount a regex expression that captures any text between the two words between the first and last client name. I can not use the clause (. *) It may capture information wrong, ie that will last beyond the name.
example:
INPUT: "Bread ..... Enterprise" -> OUTPUT: "Bread Foods Co. Enterprise"

I would like to read a specific amount of words (10 words) between the first and last name.

Does anyone know how to ride this regex?

Again, I can not use "Bread(.*)Enterprise", As will be able to find:
I bought "bread yesterday Within the next metro Sears entrerprise"

Thanks

Comment: an example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: INPUT: "Bread ..... Enterprise" -> OUTPUT: "Bread Foods Co. Enterprise"

Comment: this `"Bread.*?Enterprise" `

Comment: Right, but this regex will get a text that begins with BREAD contains 1000 words until it finds another text with ENTERPRISE. So I can not use (. *)
I would like to stress to read at most 10 words to find ENTERPRISE. This would avoid the error I mentioned. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below regex would match the all the chars from `Bread` to `Enterprise`
 only if it has a maximum of 10 words present in-between those two strings.

```
@"Bread\s*(?:\s+\S+){0,10}\s*Enterprise"
```

Comment: Avinash, I can within these 10 occurrences ignore words with size up to 2 characters?

Example "of", "a", "-", etc.
that is, if there is "of" and "a" within the occurrences, would increase from 10 to 12 words
Is it possible?